# Unable to access Sonarqube webservice API

Tags: java, web-services, sonarqube, apache-commons-httpclient, sonarqube-web

I am trying to use Sonarqube webservice API. I need to pass some parameters along with username and password to this web service api.

For that purpose I have written this following code -

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        String uri = "http://myUrl.sonar.com";
        client.getState().setCredentials(new AuthScope(uri, 8080, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
        GetMethod get = new GetMethod("http://myUrl.sonar.com/api/resources?"
                + "resource=110041&format=json&metrics=ncloc,coverage&verbose=true"
                + "&metrics=sqale_index,sqale_debt_ratio,ncloc,sqale_rating");
        get.setDoAuthentication(true);
        try {
            int status = client.executeMethod(get);
            System.out.println(status + "\n" + get.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            get.releaseConnection();
        }
```

When I run this code from Eclipse, it returns

```
401
{"err_code":401,"err_msg":"Unauthorized"}
```

Any probable reason for this? the user name and passwords are correct.

Comment: Permissions are correct?

Comment: Have the user the Browse permission on the project 110041 ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam , I have tried to browse the project from sonar website, it is working fine. Do I need to check anywhere else?

Comment: It should be good. Then, are you sure you're using the right login/password ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam yes..

Comment: Can you try to execute the WS query in a browser (on which you are connected with the same login/password) ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam . Tried. I have logged in via browser and then in another tab I tried to execute the command : http://sonar.wincor-nixdorf.com/api/resources?resource=110041&format=json&metrics=ncloc,coverage&verbose=true&metrics=sqale_index,sqale_debt_ratio,ncloc,sqale_rating. And, it is working fine and it is fetching all the results.

Comment: So it's probably the Java code that has something wrong

Comment: We have an API in order to call WS. For instance you could do : WsClient client = WsClientFactories.getDefault().newClient(HttpConnector.newBuilder()
      .url(server.getUrl())
      .credentials(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
      .build());
client.wsConnector().call(new GetRequest("http://sonar.wincor-nixdorf.com/api/resources?resource=110041&format=json&metrics=ncloc,coverage&verbose=true&metrics=sqale_index,sqale_debt_ratio,ncloc,sqale_rating"))

Comment: Thanks @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam , can you please provide some more information on this? may be some URL or documentation ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The doc is still under construction, but you can have a look in our IT : 
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/it/it-tests/src/test/java/util/ItUtils.java#L80 and https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/it/it-tests/src/test/java/it/user/BaseIdentityProviderTest.java#L272 for instance.
Librairie is available in sonar-ws http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.sonarsource.sonarqube%7Csonar-ws%7C5.6%7Cjar

Comment: Thanks @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam . Surely will have a look at it.

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam Please add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try our API to query some URL, see some examples in our ITs to use it :

- Create a WsClient with some credentials : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/it/it-tests/src/test/java/util/ItUtils.java#L80
- Use this WsClient to query a URL : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/it/it-tests/src/test/java/it/user/BaseIdentityProviderTest.java#L272.

You need to use sonar-ws, last version is available here : http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.sonarsource.sonarqube%7Csonar-ws%7C5.6%7Cjar

Comment: 404s on both these urls